# Change string read from file into special chars (e.g. "\n")

Tags: php

My script reads a file containing a replacement string and then makes a preg_replace of spaces in some text with the replacement. The idea is that the replacement file should contain any valid regex replacement.

When the replacement file contains a simple string like e.g. "xyz", it works fine. But when it contains "\n", I would like to treat it as a new line, but it doesn't work. The spaces in text are replaced literally by "\n". Here is the script:

```
$c = file_get_contents('replacements.txt');
$s = preg_replace('/ /', $c, 'some text');
file_put_contents('output.txt', $s);
```

The output.txt contains "some\ntext" when viewed in text editor.

So I added a simple if statement:

```
if ($c == '\n') {
  $c = "\n";
}
```

And now it works. But is there a more general way to deal with this problem, i.e. get the replacement string from file interpreted as a real regex replacement? Because in the future it might be a more complicated replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have indeed similar issues with other escape sequences, like `\t`, `\r`, `\x10`, ... etc.

I would suggest this solution, to turn the string into a version that has these characters interpreted.

```
$c = json_decode('"'.str_replace('"', '\"', $c).'"');
```

... then the replace will work as intended.